# how to find array of index from textfield value in Xcode?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, xcode

i need to get values from mysql and display in Xcode  textfield dynamically.( want to automatically enter the string in lastName and phoneNumber when user enters the firstName)
here my Xcode..

```
  NSError *err;
  NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.22:81/priya/sam.php"];
  NSData *dataURL=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

  NSString *name=firstname.text;
  NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:  NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
  NSArray *array=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"key"];


  lastname.text=[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"lastname"];
  phone.text=[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"phone"];
```

then how to find text array of index using first-name. 
   thanks in advance

Comment: So what has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: i am retrieving mysql values using php

Comment: first please be spesific with your question where you have to display your data in either Viewcontroller or UITableViewControlller and some another view

Comment: If the problem is in your PHP code, then show the php code; if the PHP Code isn't the problem, then there's no point in flagging as php

Comment: Do you want to automatically enter the string in **lastName** and **phoneNumber** when user enters the **firstName**?

Comment: php is working perfectly.my php result                        {"key":[{"firstName":"Peter","lastname":"Griffin"},{"firstName":"Glenn","lastname":"Quagmire"},{"firstName":"Peter","lastname":"Griffin"},{"firstName":"Glenn","lastname":"Quagmire"},{"firstName":null,"lastname":null},{"firstName":"god","lastname":"krishna"}]}

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi:exactly i am asking what you are say

Comment: User have to enter the **firstName** or it would be fetch by database?

Comment: if user type firstName means other field fetch from database

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is (do you have only 1 row instead of desired number of rows?)

Shows all rows from received data:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in array) {
    firstname.text=[item objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    lastname.text=[item objectForKey:@"lastname"];
    phone.text=[item objectForKey:@"phone"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you got for server is a dictionary and the parent key is "Key". To get array index dynamically please see the code below

```
NSMutableArray *infoArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
infoArray =[jsonArray objectForKey:@"Key"]; // this is your array with all information stored index wise.
NSLog(@"%@", infoArray);
for(int i=0; i<infoArray.count; i++)
{
NSLog(@"%@", [[infoArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"firstname"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[infoArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"lastnamename"]);
}
```

or
The issue is with PHP side ask them to replace "[" and "]" with "(" and ")".

Hope this will help

Comment: okay your NSArray.. i guess issue is with  {"key":[{"firstName": ... here "[" and "]" should be replaced with "(" and ")" . Ask your PHP guys to change it it will work for sure